# Failing to create SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to create a SearchView for one of my 4 MenuItems, that are being created programmatically, however I am getting a NPE when I use xml for my SearchView.

xml/search_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/simpleSearchView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</SearchView>
```

Java

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.search_card, 1, R.string.search_card);
        searchItem.setIcon(R.drawable.search);
        searchItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.simpleSearchView);
        searchItem.setActionView(searchView);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            // enters here
        }

        MenuItem trashCardItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.delete_card, 2, R.string.delete_card);
        ...
    }
```

How can I resolve this so I can have one of my MenuItems act as a SearchView?

Comment: Can you add your full Activity code?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman my activity is quite large tbh..is in there anything in particular I should show?

Comment: Put `search_view.xml` into `layout` directory, and let's see the result.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH still no luck, the SearchView is still null after I have moved the search_view.xml from xml to layout directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `searchItem.setActionView()` method needs a view as input. In your case, you must inflate your layout instead of calling `findViewById(R.id.simpleSearchView)` method. So change

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.simpleSearchView);
```

to

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.search_view, null);
```

will fix the problem. 
BTW, NPE is not related to this part of your code. Check the stack trace to find source of exception.